# Grammar stucture make someone something

Tags: grammar

As you know, there are some structures which let us form sentences by using "make". Like

```
 make + noun = adjective
```

which I used to make the first sentence of mine.

My question is: Is there also a structure to make a sentence by using the pattern

```
make + noun = noun
```

which I used to build the second sentence?

> She made me happy.
>   She made me her colleague or partner.

Are these sentences correct?

Comment: It's a predicative complement, so not only regular noun phrases and adjective phrases work, but also bare role noun phrases: "She made me treasurer."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You make me happy.
>
> She makes me angry.
>
> He made me a partner.

In all of these sentences, "make" means "to cause to become". This is in contrast to the definition of make as "to construct, fabricate, assemble".

You can differentiate these meanings because the object of each sentence - "happy", "angry", "a partner" - are not things that can be fabricated or constructed.

Comment: I'm glad you left out *She made me her colleague*. I really can't imagine even a contrived context where anyone would actually *say* that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps:  "I used to work freelance for her but then she hired me and made me her colleague."

Answer (score 3):

Because this type of structure is laden with the possibility of ambiguity, it's very easy to end up with the following type of construction, for varying potential degrees of amusement

> "My wife made me a happy man."
>
> "If I gave her the wool, do you think she'd make me one, too?"

<sup>I don't think this is an answer, but it's a pitfall to be aware of</sup>